# kotlin quiz i can't color answer because don't run ContextCompat

Tags: kotlin

Could you help me with the following code, I can't get it to paint the correct option green, or show the animation, of the CorrectResponse function.
If I delete the `defaultColors()` function, the green color is shown, but it remains in the next question.
when I write the default function it doesn't execute the code:

```
tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
```

I have tried to insert a sleep to `defaultColors()` to see the color `correct_option_border_bg(green)` but it is not displayed.
Any advice?

```
class QuestionActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var quizzes: MutableList<Quiz>? = null
    var contadorPregunta = 0
    var questions: MutableMap<String, Question>? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_question)

    // VISUALIZACION PREGUNTAS
    private fun bindViews() {
        if (contadorPregunta == questions!!.size) { // last question
            Toast.makeText(this, "HAS COMPLETADO TODAS LAS PREGUNTAS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        else{
            defaultColors()
        }

        val pregunta = indicePreguntas[contadorPregunta]
        val question = questions!!["question$pregunta"]
        question?.let {
            tvDescription.text = it.description
            tv_option_one.text = it.option1
            tv_option_two.text = it.option2
            tv_option_three.text = it.option3
            tv_option_four.text = it.option4
            val respuesta = it.answer

            tv_option_one.setOnClickListener {
                if (tv_option_one.text == respuesta) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaCorrecta()
                } else {
                    tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaFallada()
                }

            }
            tv_option_two.setOnClickListener {

                if (tv_option_two.text == respuesta) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    tv_option_two.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaCorrecta()
                } else {
                    tv_option_two.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaFallada()

                }
            }
            tv_option_three.setOnClickListener {

                if (tv_option_three.text == respuesta) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    tv_option_three.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
                    contadorPregunta++
                    indicePreguntas[contadorPregunta]
                } else {
                    tv_option_three.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaFallada()

                }
            }
            tv_option_four.setOnClickListener {

                if (tv_option_four.text == respuesta) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "RESPUESTA CORRECTA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    tv_option_four.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.correct_option_border_bg)
                } else {
                    tv_option_four.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.wrong_option_border_bg)
                    respuestaFallada()

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun defaultColors() {
        tv_option_one.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_option_border_bg)
        tv_option_two.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_option_border_bg)
        tv_option_three.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_option_border_bg)
        tv_option_four.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.default_option_border_bg)
        ivAcierto.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

    }

    private fun respuestaCorrecta() {
        // Ver animacion
        ivAcierto.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        ivAcierto.animate().apply {
            duration=1000
            rotationYBy(1400f)
        }.start()
        contadorPregunta++
        indicePreguntas[contadorPregunta]
        Thread.sleep(2_000)
        bindViews()
    }

    private fun respuestaFallada() {
        //Thread.sleep(1_000)
        // FALLO EN EL TEST
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_one_style_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.dialog_one_style_message)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_one_style_positive_btn) { view, _ ->
                view.dismiss()
                val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
                val json = Gson().toJson(quizzes!![0])
                intent.putExtra("QUIZ", json)

                startActivity(intent)
            }
            .setCancelable(false)
            .create()
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give a couple of notes here: please use English when you write code, cause I have no idea what "pregunta" is and don't do this `!!` ... find other way to deal with nullables.

In `respuestaCorrecta` you call `bindViews`, which calls `defaultColors` and your correct color is getting overrided. As I can see, you want to delay calling `bindViews` by adding 2 sec sleep...

This is a bad idea. See your code runs in a main thread, in the same thread where rendering of Android Views happens... So making it sleep for 2 sec will make sure that no view will render for this period of time, and a user will not see anything in the app - no animation, no color changes, etc.

Thread.sleep cannot be used within main thread. However, if you want something to change after 2 sec, you can post an update. Like this:

```
tv_option_one.postDelayed({
    bindViews()                          
}, 2000)
```

lambda is what will be called after a delay

2000 is a delay in millis